# Heroku application error Connection error: SSL_connect: certificate verify failed

Tags: ssl, heroku, connection, certificate

I made minor code changes, and pushed to heroku.

Now I get the following errors in a loop (several per second when not hitting the app):

2014-03-18T16:24:24.934863+00:00 app[web.1]: [Tue Mar 18 16:24:24 2014] Connection error: SSL_connect: certificate verify failed [reporter/ssl.cc:743] [Oboe-SSL_reporter-warn 2]
2014-03-18T16:24:24.916589+00:00 app[web.1]: [Tue Mar 18 16:24:24 2014] Connection error: SSL_connect: certificate verify failed [reporter/ssl.cc:743] [Oboe-SSL_reporter-warn 2]

I've reverted to previous versions and would still get it starting when i log in.  I didn't modify any of the authentication code though.
Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: This was a problem with TraceView.  I had installed the gem and it was having trouble connecting it seems.
Uninstalled it works again.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with TraceView.  I had installed the gem and it was having trouble connecting it seems.
Uninstalled it works again.